# Zoom Camera from C# in Unity

Tags: unity, camera

I am creating endless running game. I want to zoom camera when player dies to the player. I have tried using camera.FieldOfView, but it does not work. Is there another way to zoom In camera to the object when particular condition becomes true.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the trick you can use smooth camera follow when your player dies

Comment: can you explain further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said the trick you can use is to just activate Smooth Camera Follow when your player dies. You can take the script for `Smooth Follow` from [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114742/how-can-i-do-slow-parent-in-unity/114782#114782).

Now,

- Attach it to camera.
- Play and properly configure it, as you want.
- Disable the script.
- Enable it when your player dies.

**Note:** This is for 3D environment, as you are trying to change FOV of camera, which is applicable in perspective view. If you are developing a 2D game then let me know.

**Update:** As you already have camera follow script for your 2D game, just change the `Camera.main.orthographicSize`.

```
Camera.main.orthographicSize = 1;
```

You can also make a coroutine for some smooth effect

```
IEnumerator ZoomIn ()
    {
        while (Camera.main.orthographicSize > 1) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.01f);
            Camera.main.orthographicSize -= 0.1f;
        }
    }
```

Just call `StartCoroutine ("ZoomIn");` once when your player dies.

Comment: Then FOV is obviously not gonna work :) I'm outside for a break, give me 10 minutes:)

Comment: Wait a minute, of you are developing an endless runner then you already must have a camera follow script? Right?

Comment: Then change the size attribute instead of field of view

Comment: orthographicSize??

Comment: Check the edits in answer

Comment: This made me laugh.

Comment: @Jon yo man... You can understand ;)