# Move Camera When Player Move C#

Tags: unity, c#, android, camera, movement

i developing side Scrolling endless Game. i want to Change X Axis of camera as player moving to Right. and i almost Done That. but the problem is when move Camera to the Right then its look so stiff in Android Device not Move Smooth.
That's the code I Write in  my Script to move Camera when player move.

```
public static float offsetX;

void Update () {

    if (BirdScript.instance != null) {

        if (BirdScript.instance.isAlive) {
            MoveTheCamera ();
        }
    }

}

void MoveTheCamera() {
    Vector3 temp = transform.position;
    temp.x = BirdScript.instance.GetPositionX () + offsetX;
    transform.position = temp;

}
```

and in my Player Script(BirdScript.cs) i also set my player Position and also Get in CameraScript

```
void Awake() {

   setCameraX();

}

void setCameraX() {

    CameraScript.offsetX = (Camera.main.transform.position.x - transform.position.x) - 1f;

}

public float GetPositionX(){

    return transform.position.x;
}
```

what should i do to move my camera smoothly in device? thanks.....

Answer (score 4):

use **Mathf.Lerp** for smooth transform [For more details click here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SmoothCamera2D : MonoBehaviour {

 public float dampTime = 0.15f;
 private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
 public Transform target;

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () 
 {
     if (target)
     {
         Vector3 point = camera.WorldToViewportPoint(target.position);
         Vector3 delta = target.position - camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, point.z)); //(new Vector3(point.x, 0.5, 0.5));
         Vector3 destination = transform.position + delta;
         transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, destination, ref velocity, dampTime);
     }
 }
}
```

Edit 2;

for a 2D Endless Runner no need to move the camera. set the camera as constant and scroll the background. it ll give player moving effect

[Eg 1.](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/infinite-runner)

[Eg 2.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/1xdqur/making_a_2d_endless_runner/)

Click the link and Read the Complete documentation and see video tutorial. They gave complete tutorial about 2d endless runner game

Comment: i use this,,, but no change. output will be same...in device..

Comment: instead of Time.time use Time.deltatime * 1.0f;

Comment: i develop 2D Game not 3D.. i just move Camera in X Axis when Player move endless.

Comment: i edited my post check it now

Comment: i used this code but the problem is as it is,,, no change..... @Manoj

Comment: can you please tell. what kind of game you are trying to create in 2D?

Comment: i want to move Camera when my player position... For Ex; Game like Hill Climb.... want to do that same camera move effect

Comment: @DarshanSoni i edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

There's a script called "SmoothFollow" provided by unity itself in the Standard Assets package. 
You should be able to modify that to make a sidescroller.

Answer (score 0):

### For 3D

If you are developing 3D game then you can get your relevant stuff from [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114742/how-can-i-make-camera-to-follow-smoothly/114782#114782)

### For 2D

If you are developing 2D game then I have a script, that will help you most probably.

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

```
public class CameraFollow2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Camera Follow")]
    public float _dampTime = 0.15f;
    public Transform _target;

    // These public booleans allow you to move in any specific direction
    public bool _followX = true;
    public bool _followY = true;

    private Vector3 _velocity = Vector3.zero;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (_target) {
            Vector3 point = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint (_target.position);
            Vector3 delta = _target.position - Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (0.5f, 0.5f, point.z)); //(new Vector3(0.5, 0.5, point.z));
            Vector3 destination = transform.position + delta;
            transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp (transform.position, new Vector3 (_followX ? destination.x : transform.position.x,
                                                                                     _followY ? destination.y : transform.position.y,
                                                                                     transform.position.z), ref _velocity, _dampTime);
        }

    }
}
```

In both cases, drop the script to your `Camera`. Assign target to it from inspector and configure it according to your need.

Comment: ya i try this type Code that's work but only unity Editor.... when i Run my Game in Android Device then Not Work Perfectly... Camera not Follow Player Smoothly.... & in unity Editor That's Work. i don't know how to solve this problem...