# Switching camera position on collision

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to switch the camera to another object on collision.

This is what I've tried to do:

```
    public Camera switchCamera1;
public GameObject player2;

private Vector3 offset;

void Start () {
    offset = transform.position - player2.transform.position;
}

void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) {
    if (col.gameObject.name == "triggerCube") {
        //SceneManager.LoadScene ("test2");
        Debug.Log ("HIT SOMETHING");
        setWinText ();


        switchCamera1.transform.position = player2.transform.position + offset;


    }
}
```

However it simply doesn't work. I've set my camera to switchCamera1, I've set the other object to player2. The script is assigned to the collider object.

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps forgetting to reparent the camera so it follows player2?

```
switchCamera1.transform.SetParent(player2.transform);
```

Not sure this is what you're after but perhaps a better explanation of the effect you're trying to achieve is required.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: I tried removing the camera from the parent and I also tried your code but nothing works still.

I'm having a collision in my game, where the camera follows object 1 into the collision. After the collision I want the camera to pan over to object 2, a few units away from the collision and follow that unit.

Comment: I see the problem tho, I have a camera script that keeps following object 1. Should I be writing this collision script in the original collision script or on the camera script? I dont know how to do it in the camera one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd suggest to use `Smooth Follow` script rather than making it child (if it is not particularly required).

- You can grab the `Camera Follow` code from [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114742/how-can-i-make-camera-to-follow-smoothly/114782#114782)
- Attach it to your camera (please un-child your camera first)
- Drop the initial target in Target in just attached `Smooth Follow` script.
- Access this script in your current script in which you want to play with it. (By `public SmoothFollow smoothFollw;` or by `FindObjectOfType< SmoothFollow>()` whatever you want)
- Now change the target on collision by changing its `target` transform value.

Hope this helps.